# How to lazy load map component using useEffect hook for React/Next js site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, next.js

I placed a Google Maps API component on the index page of my Next js site but it's slowing down the load by a crazy amount (something like 500ms).

Is there a way for me to delay the component until after page load using the useEffect hook or in another concise way?

I want to increase the loading speed (and performance score) of the site.

```
export default function Home() {
  return (

    <div className={styles.main}>
      <Layout>
        <main className={styles.content}> 

          **<div className={styles.mapContainer}>
            <Map  className={styles.map}/>**

          </div>
        </main>
      </Layout>
    </div>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next.js provides a `dynamic` helper that will only load the component when it would render to the page.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Map = dynamic(() => import('components/MapOrWhatever'));

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
      <Layout>
        <main className={styles.content}> 
          <div className={styles.mapContainer}>
            <Map  className={styles.map}/>
          </div>
        </main>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can also specify options for the `dynamic` function as the second argument:

```
const Map = dynamic(() => import('components/MapOrWhatever'), {
    ssr: false, // do not render this on the server side render
    loading: () => <div>Loading Map...</div>, // placeholder component
});
```

If you want to delay rendering (and therefore loading) your component until a specific time, then yes, you could use an effect or other hook to toggle rendering the map. As an example:

```
export default function Home() {
  const [showMap, setShowMap] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Set the map to load 2 seconds after first render
    const timeOut = setTimeout(() => setShowMap(true), 2000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeOut);
  }, []);

  // <Map> will only load when showMap is true
  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
      <Layout>
        <main className={styles.content}> 
          {showMap && <div className={styles.mapContainer}>
            <Map  className={styles.map}/>
          </div>}
        </main>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In practice, it's better to dynamically load components that are hidden behind some kind of interaction, like changing tabs in the app to load a new route, or clicking a "View Map" button. Putting it behind a `setTimeout` isn't very productive and you're just artificially delaying the loading of components arbitrarily without really thinking it through. But, I've included it as an example to show how dynamic components only load once they should render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using the dynamic import decreased my lighthouse rating by like 10 points! Any idea why that may be? 
Otherwise the setTimeout worked perfectly at 2s.

Comment: By the way, the difference between the dynamic import and the timeout was 26 points for mobile ... That's crazy

Comment: Part of what Lighthouse measures is time to first paint and time to first interactive, both of which are heavily influenced by the main bundle size, which itself impacts JavaScript parse time and probably other things. Deferring UI load until later (ideally, just-in-time when it needs to render) can have a big impact there. Just be careful you don't get tunnel vision on Lighthouse - it's a useful tool but do qualitative testing of your own to see how the perceived page load time and UI interactivity is affected. If I've answered your question please mark it as the "accepted" answer :)